# See details about process from /proc in htop?

Tags: htop

Is there a way to get extra details about running process in `htop` ?

Like there is process starting time (to identify if process recently crashed/restarted)? Default TIME+ htop column shown CPU clock time, not timestamp when process started....

Like: `ps -p $PID -o etime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in `htop` press `F2` and then go down to `Columns`. You can customize which columns to show and in which order, go to the right to the Available columns, `STARTTIME` is the one you need, press `F5` to add it to the Active Columns list. You can customize the list more by reordering the items. After you finish, press `F10` to go back to the main screen.

The changes are persisted in your `htoprc` file (usually in `~/.config/htoprc`), so the column will be there in future calls to `htop`